# Java: How to replace doPost, doGet in deprecated WebSocketServlet class

Tags: java, java-websocket

In older Java versions you could extend a class with WebSocketServlet, and because WebSocketServlet itself extended HttpServlet it was possible to add CRUD method, such as doGet(...), doPost(...) etc in the class.

However, now WebSocketServlet is deprecated and and using @ServerEndpoint with @OnOpen, @OnMessage, etc does not provide any "listen to doGet, doPost" messages. How can I migrate something like this?

```
public class Test extends WebSocketServlet 
{
   String something = "";

   @Override 
   protected StreamInBound createWebSocketInbound(String string, HttpServletRequest hsr)
   {
       // DO STUFF
   }

   @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException,IOException
   {
        this.something = "get";
   }
}
```

Where do put doGet(...) and doPost(...)?

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/test")
public class Test {
    
  @OnOpen
  public void onOpen(Session session) {
    // DO STUFF
  }

  @OnMessage
  public String onMessage(String message, Session session) {
    // DO STUFF
  }
    
  @OnClose
  public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
    // DO STUFF
  }
}
```

Also notice that I need to change a variable from the doGet(...) method that exist in the Test class.

Thanks!

Comment: Within `onMessage`!?

Comment: Yes, but web socket communication is different than sending HTTP requests as it is a completely different protocol. I still need to listen to incoming HTTP requests.

Comment: Do you have an example where you actually sent GET and POST requests via a websocket? That is simply not what websockets are normally used for. Obviously you can send whatever data you want through there but putting HTTP on top makes little sense. Just change your backend code to only have onMessage and see what happens if a client actually makes a GET or POST request against it.